# How are free points used?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse, translations, werewolf-20th-anniversary

In my translated version of Werewolf The Apocalypse, 20th Anniversary, it reads that the 15 free points on character creation can be used in two different ways:

On page 114, the 15 free points are to be used as for fixed amounts:

- Rasgo Coste
- Atributos 5 por círculo
- Habilidades 2 por círculo
- Trasfondos 1 por círculo
- Dones 7 por Don (sólo de nivel uno)
- Rabia 1 por círculo
- Gnosis 2 por círculo
- Fuerza de Voluntad 1 por círculo

but on page 117 it asks to check the table on page 244, which reads:

- Rasgo Coste
- Atributo Puntuación actual x 4
- Habilidad Puntuación actual x 2
- Nueva Habilidad 3
- Don Nivel de Don x 3
- Don de otra Raza, Auspicio o Tribu Nivel de Don x 5
- Rabia Puntuación actual
- Gnosis Puntuación actual x 2
- Fuerza de Voluntad Puntuación actual

Which one to use?

Comment: @Yasskier Don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the English-language version of World of Darkness games, Freebie point costs are applied in set values.

> Vampire the Masquerade 20th Edition
>   Freebie Points Trait Cost
>   Attribute 5 per dot
>   Ability 2 per dot
>   Discipline 7 per dot
>   Background 1 per dot
>   Virtue 2 per dot
>   Humanity/Path 2 per dot
>   Willpower 1 per dot

The table on 244 looks like it might be Experience Point costs.

> VtM 20th Edition
>   Experience Costs Trait Cost
>   New Ability 3
>   New Discipline 10
>   New Path (Necromancy or Thaumaturgy) 7
>   Attribute current rating x 4
>   Ability current rating x 2
>   Clan Discipline current rating x 5*
>   Other Discipline current rating x 7*
>   Secondary Path (Necromancy or Thaumaturgy) current rating x 4
>   Virtue current rating x 2**
>   Humanity or Path of Enlightenment current rating x 2
>   Willpower current rating
>   * Caitiff have no Clan-based Disciplines, just as they have no Clan. For them, the cost of raising all Disciplines is the current rating x 6. This is both the curse and the blessing of being Clanless.
>   ** Increasing a Virtue through experience does not increase Traits based on that Virtue (Humanity, Path, Willpower).

Freebie points are bonus points granted at character generation to allow you some additional customization for your character. Experience points, on the other hand, are awarded by the GM for roleplay, reaching milestones, or otherwise impressing him or her.

Per @Envite's comment

> I've e-mailed the editors Biblioteca Oscura and they have confirmed me that page 117 should refer to table on page 114, not 244, and that it is an error on the original English version.

Comment: Can you flesh out the difference between freebie points and experience points in your answer?  That might help the querent understand your answer a bit more.

Comment: Added a comparison to the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Maybe an errata in the translation. I would like to check the english version of WtA-20

Comment: @Envite Appreciate the acceptance, but it's generally a good idea to hold off on accepting an answer for 24 hours. Someone might come along with a better answer (one that draws on the actual W20 book, for example, instead of generalizing using the V20 book).

Comment: I've e-mailed the editors Biblioteca Oscura and they have confirmed me that page 117 should refer to table on page 114, not 244, and that it is an error on the original English version.